# TakeFirst() in scrapy to take all data

Tags: python, scrapy

I am really beginner and have this code:

```
class ActivityItem(scrapy.Item):
Id = scrapy.Field(
output_processor=TakeFirst()
)
EconomicActivityDescription = scrapy.Field(
output_processor=TakeFirst()
)
```

What should I do, when want to ActivityItem scrapy all, not only first not null?ň

```
output_processor=TakeFirst()
```

Comment: don't use `TakeFirst` but process data directly in Spider - find all values (ie. using `.get()`)  and create `ActivityItem` for every value separatelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the built in processors as described in the [docs](https://itemloaders.readthedocs.io/en/latest/built-in-processors.html#built-in-processors).

You can use `Join` if you want to return all the items joined by a given separator or use `Identity` to return the value as a list of all the items.

1. Using `Join`

```py
from itemloaders.processors import Join
class ActivityItem(scrapy.Item):
  Id = scrapy.Field(output_processor=Join(","))
  EconomicActivityDescription = scrapy.Field(output_processor=Join(","))
```

2. Using `Identity`

```py
from itemloaders.processors import Identity
class ActivityItem(scrapy.Item):
  Id = scrapy.Field(output_processor=Identity())
  EconomicActivityDescription = scrapy.Field(output_processor=Identity())
```